# Adding chars before and after each word in a string

Tags: c#

Imagine we have a string as :

```
String mystring = "A,B,C,D";
```

I would like to add an apostrophe before and after each word in my string.Such as:

```
"'A','B','C','D'"
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Before and after each *word*? What about this string: "A, Something here, C", would you want this: "'A', 'Something' 'here', 'C'" ?

Comment: Actually those letters are words,lazy me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's your definition of a word?  Anything between commas?

First get the words:

```
var words = mystring.Split(',');
```

Then add the apostrophes:

```
words = words.Select(w => String.Format("'{0}'", w));
```

And turn them back into one string:

```
var mynewstring = String.Join(",", words);
```

Comment: 1 line: `var words = string.Join(",", mystring.Split(',').Select(w => string.Format("'{0}'", w)));`

Answer (score 5):

```
mystring = "'" + mystring.replace(",", "','") + "'";
```

Comment: +1 I wrote totally the same answer and couldn't post it because You were faster :)

Comment: Thanks. Usually, I'd have also gone for some splitting way of doing it, but in this case this oneliner does exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I would let each "word" be determined by the regex `\b` word boundary. So, you have:

```
var output = Regex.Replace("A,B,C,D", @"(\b)", @"'$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "a,b,c,d";

string.Format("'{0}'", str.Replace(",", "','"));
```

or

```
string str = "a,b,c,d";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length * 2 + 2);

foreach (var c in str.ToCharArray())
{
    sb.AppendFormat((c == ',' ? "{0}" : "'{0}'"), c);
}

str = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string mystring = "A,B,C,D";
string[] array = mystring.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string newstring = "";
foreach (var item in array)
{
    newstring += "'" + item + "',";
}
newstring = newstring.Remove(newstring.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(newstring);
```

Output will be;

```
'A','B','C','D'
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/9s92TI).

Or more simple;

```
string mystring = "A,B,C,D";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("'{0}'", mystring.Replace(",", "','")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressions to solve this problem
like this:

string words= "A,B,C,D";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\w+)");
words = reg.Replace(words, match=> { return string.Format("'{0}'", match.Groups[1].Value); });